# Правильная группировка

Tags: mysql, sql

Добрый день, хочу узнать, правильно ли я использую группировку по месяцам, сама группировка возвращает корректные данные, но работает очень медленно.
Вот кусок кода, просто убрал большую часть вложенных SELECT-ов:

```
SELECT month(`requests`.`date`) as dt,
/** Общая статистика **/

/* Определить: каличество поступивших заявок */
(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM `object_requests`
        LEFT JOIN `requests` ON `object_requests`.`id_request` = `requests`.`id`
    WHERE
        DATE(`requests`.`date`) >= DATE(?) AND
        DATE(`requests`.`date`) <= DATE(?) AND
        month(`requests`.`date`)=`dt`
) as `all_requests`,

/* Определить: каличество включенных в план заявок */
(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM `object_requests`
        LEFT JOIN `requests` ON `object_requests`.`id_request` = `requests`.`id`
    WHERE
        `requests`.`status` = 0 AND
        DATE(`requests`.`date`) >= DATE(?) AND
        DATE(`requests`.`date`) <= DATE(?) AND
        month(`requests`.`date`)=`dt`
) as `included_requests`
FROM `object_requests`
LEFT JOIN `requests` ON `object_requests`.`id_request` = `requests`.`id`

WHERE DATE(requests.date) >= DATE(?) AND DATE(requests.date) <= DATE(?) GROUP BY month(requests.date) ORDER BY date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не слишком уверен, как там в диалекте MySQL. Попробуйте по такому образцу на T-SQL

```
SELECT month(`requests`.`date`) as dt, 
COUNT(*), SUM(CASE WHEN `requests`.`status` = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM `object_requests` 
LEFT JOIN `requests` ON `object_requests`.`id_request` = `requests`.`id` 
WHERE DATE(requests.date) >= DATE(?) AND DATE(requests.date) <= DATE(?) GROUP BY month(requests.date) ORDER BY date
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую зелье мелкомягких.
Может еще подскажешь, а LEFT JOIN надо на каждый вложенный под запрос или хватит и основного?

Comment: Попробовал))) спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! попытаюсь остальные селекты к такому же алгоритму привести.